# Querying freebase for Entity and Predicte

Tags: freebase, mql

I trying to use freebase for my project. I have been successful in getting required data using MQL queries. As a next step in the project I want to query freebase for the  `subject predicate object`  triples. For example, I want to know whether information like `Person X Lives in City Y`  is present in the freebase. In the knowledge bases like NELL it is possible to get the predicate and the object connected to the given subject as they are stored in a graph structure.

Another question is that, Given a triple  `Subject Predicate Object`  Whether it is possible to get the type of the entities acting as  `Subject`  and  `Object`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need something like this:

```
[{
  "type": "/type/link",
  "source": {
    "id": "/m/035qy",
    "type": []
  },
  "master_property": "/location/location/contains",
  "target": {
    "id": "/m/08v97b",
    "type": []
  },
  "target_value": null
}]
```

This will return the types of the subject (source) for the predicate `/location/location/contains` and the types of the object (target).